# How to remove namespace with PHP SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an XML structure that needs to look like this to work:

```
<yq1:ZwsCreateInfoRec xmlns:yq1="urn:test-com:document:test:soap:functions:mc-style">
      <ItPrice>1337</ItPrices>
</yq1:ZwsCreateInfoRec>
```

To try and achieve this I'm using SimpleXMLElement like this:

```
$xml = SimpleXMLElement('<yq1:ZwsCreteMaterialFrRef xmlns:yq1="urn:test-com:document:test:soap:functions:mc-style"></yq1:ZwsCreteMaterialFrRef>');
$xml->addChild('ItPrice', '1337');
```

When I now run `$xml->asXML()` it shows me this (Note the namespace on the ItPrice node):

```
<yq1:ZwsCreateInfoRec xmlns:yq1="urn:test-com:document:test:soap:functions:mc-style">
      <yq1:ItPrice>1337</yq1:ItPrices>
</yq1:ZwsCreateInfoRec>
```

For some reason the WebService doesn't work if I have the namespace on the child nodes like that but if I remove them it works. Is there a way for me to remove this or do I have to loop through this as a string and remove them manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 3rd parameter with blank value for addChild method.  `$xml->addChild('ItPrice', '1337', '');`

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<yq1:ZwsCreteMaterialFrRef xmlns:yq1="urn:test-com:document:test:soap:functions:mc-style"></yq1:ZwsCreteMaterialFrRef>');
$namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces();
$xml->addChild('ItPrice', '1337', '');
echo  $xml->asXml();
```

Comment: This adds a tag like `<ItPrice xmlns="">1337</itPrice>` which seams to be the same thing as `<ItPrice>1337</ItPrice>`. Is that correct?

Comment: ` <yq1:ItPrice>1337</yq1:ItPrices>` it will remove `yq1` namespace